# How to patch up the pole holes in WhirlyGlobe

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Does anybody know how can I patch the pole holes when I'm trying to load Earth surface using `addQuadEarthLayerWithRemoteSource` method in WhirlyGlobe framework? Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll refer you to the discussion here:
https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe/issues/2

In any case, it should be resolved within in the next few days.

If you're in a hurry, you could just make up a couple of vectors, mark them as filled and stick them in the right spots.